# a maximum modulus problem

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $0<r<R$ and $A=\{z:r\leq |z| \leq R\}$. Prove that there is a
>   positive number $\epsilon >0$ such that for each polynomial $p$,
>   $$\sup \{|p(z)-z^{-1}|:z\in A\}\geq \epsilon $$

I know I should use maximum modulus to solve it, it can take maximum on $\partial A$, but I do not know how to find $\epsilon$. This problem form Conway Functions of one complex Variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, finding an explicit $\epsilon$ is feasible:

Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{R}\right)$. Then if $p$ is a polynomial with

$$\sup \{ \lvert p(z) - z^{-1}\rvert : \lvert z\rvert = R\} < \epsilon$$

it follows that $\lvert p(z)\rvert < \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{R}\right)$ on the circle $\lvert z\rvert = R$, and by the maximum modulus principle on the disk $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant R$. In particular, it follows that $\lvert p(z)\rvert < \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{R}\right)$ for $\lvert z\rvert = r$, and thus $\lvert p(z) - z^{-1}\rvert > \epsilon$ for $\lvert z\rvert = r$, whence

$$\sup \{ \lvert p(z) - z^{-1}\rvert : z\in A\} > \epsilon.$$

---

If we had a more complicated function than $z^{-1}$, finding an explicit $\epsilon$ would in general be difficult. But one need not necessarily find an explicit $\epsilon$, one can prove the existence without that.

So let $f$ a meromorphic function on a neighbourhood of the disk $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant R\}$ with at least one pole in $\{z : \lvert z\rvert < r\}$ and no pole in $A$ (or, more generally, any function holomorphic on $A$ that has no holomorphic continuation to the disk $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant R\}$). Suppose that no $\epsilon > 0$ with $\sup \{ \lvert p(z) - f(z)\rvert : z \in A\} \geqslant \epsilon$ for all polynomials $p$ exists, i.e.

$$\bigl(\forall \epsilon > 0\bigr) \bigl(\exists p\bigr)\bigl(\sup \{ \lvert p(z) - f(z)\rvert : z\in A\} < \epsilon\bigr).\tag{$\ast$}$$

From that assumption, you derive a contradiction, using the maximum modulus principle.

Under the assumption $(\ast)$, there is a sequence $(p_n)$ of polynomials converging to $f$ uniformly on $A$. Now, for polynomials $p,q$, we have

$$\sup \{ \lvert p(z) - q(z)\rvert : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant R\} = \sup \{ \lvert p(z) - q(z)\rvert : z \in A\} = \max \{ \lvert p(z) - q(z)\rvert : \lvert z\rvert = R\}$$

by the maximum modulus principle. What does that imply for the sequence $(p_n)$? Why does that contradict $p_n \to f$ on $A$?

Comment: Thanks  a lot, can you tell me why you introduce a new polynomial $q$, and how can you get this equality$\sup \{ \lvert p(z) - q(z)\rvert : \lvert z\rvert < R\} = \sup \{ \lvert p(z) - q(z)\rvert : z \in A\} = \max \{ \lvert p(z) - q(z)\rvert : \lvert z\rvert = R\}$, thanks

Comment: The target is to deduce that if we have a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$ that converges to $f$ uniformly on $A$, then the sequence converges uniformly on the disk $\{z : \lvert z\rvert < R\}$. Since $f$ is not holomorphic on that whole disk, we need to look at $\lvert p_n(z) - p_m(z)\rvert$, that is, the difference of two polynomials; these are $p$ and $q$. We have the inequalities $$\sup \{\ldots : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant R\} \geqslant \sup \{\ldots : z\in A\} \geqslant \sup \{ \ldots : \lvert z\rvert = R\}$$ by inclusion of the sets $z$ is taken from.

Comment: The equality of the outer terms is just the maximum principle (since $p-q$ is holomorphic on the whole disk). Whether one takes $\lvert z\rvert < R$ or $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant R$ in the first supremum doesn't matter, since $p-q$ is continuous and the open disk is dense in the closed disk. But for uniformity of style, I should better have taken $\leqslant$, changing that now.